# Windows 7 permissions are set but access is denied

Tags: windows-7, permissions

This is my Administrators group, I have two users on the computer in the group but only 1 of them has access to a file. The one that has access is the creator of the file (owner).

[image: http://i58.tinypic.com/2a9plbd.png]

I have a file, used to generate logs for our application. It's stored in the "ProgramData" folder. Any user can install the application and it should write to the single log file. Here's the permissions for the file. It's set on the app folder itself recursively:

[image: http://i59.tinypic.com/wbp8no.png]

In order for the other user to have access, I have to set the group "my-pc\Users" to full control. Even though there should be overlap from the Administrators group which has full control.

Anyone know what's going on here? Is this just some Windows quirk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the impact of the [User Account Control](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00d04415-2b2f-422c-b70e-b18ff918c281) (UAC) which is part of Windows since Vista. Your account is in admin group, but has a filtered token which is effectively standard user rights. So you have to grant the normal users group also access to files/folders.

Comment: Or "Run as administrator" whatever application you are trying to access the files with

Comment: Or give the other user explicit permissions on the log file.

Comment: Adding a permissions adjustment on startup. Thanks.